# Утворення слова повітаний

Tags: дієприкметники

Спочатку мене зацікавило, як правильно казати "повішати" чи "повісити".
Почала шукати. На http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53407/31848.html знайшла, що вживаються обидва варіанти

> ПОВІСИТИ , ПОВІШАТИ
>           ПОВІСИТИ – ПОВІШАТИ
>           Повісити, -ішу, -ісиш. Зачепивши, надати чомусь висячого положення; скарати когось через повішення тощо. Дієприкм. повішений.
>           Повішати. Повісити, почепити все або багато чогось; скарати всіх або багатьох. Дієприкм. повітаний.

І помітила дієприкметник повітаний.
Чому саме така форма? Дуже дивна, як на мене. Особисто я не чула раніше це слово.

Comment: Лиш припускају, шчо то від [вити 2](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyty).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можливо у книзі ["Прадавність української мови"](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Hubernachuk_Stanisalav/Pradavnist_ukrainskoi_movy.pdf) (256 ст) знайдеться відповідь на ваше запитання:

> *Мовна   тотожність    стосується    і    закінчень    дієприкметників,    коли    замість    закінчення    -ений  вживалось  у княжу  добу  і 
>   **вживається  носіями  названих   говірок**
>
>   і нині  закінчення   -яний,  -аний.  А.   Кримський   відшукав   у 
>   руко- писах    Русі-України   такі   приклади   на   цю   рису:
>
>   посажаний,    (замість   —   посажений),  повітаний,   засмоляний,
>
>   казняний.*

Про те, що таке слово характерне для княжої доби, можна й зрозуміти по тому, що досить часто воно зустрічається у текстах того часу, ось, наприклад, цитати із Києво-Печерського патерика:

> І запитав їх, на яку ж смерть його засуджено. «На дереві має бути
>   повітаний»...

Також ще цитата із "Прадавності української мови", але взята вже із [цього сайту](http://www.personal-plus.net/274/3335.html):

> У давньокиївських пам’ятках зустрічається й характерне для сучасних
>   говірок Київщини змішування звуків -Т- з -К- у написанні одних і тих
>   же слів чи імен: Мартіян і Маркіян, Овдотья і Овдокья.

Гадаю, що можливо якесь таке ж змішування сталося із звуками -ш- і -т- у цьому слові і вийшло "повітаний".

Comment: дуже цікаво, дякую)

Comment: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/5189

Comment: Отже, це жахливе "змішування" сталося "завдяки" поганому розрізнюванню літер _"ш"_ і _"т"_ якоюсь програмою OCR :)

Answer (score 6):

Це просто описка (точніше, помилка розпізнавання) — ось фрагмент з оригінального (нерозпізнаного) «Словника-довiдника з українського лiтературного слововживання» С. І. Головащука (Київ, «Наукова думка», 2004; натиснути для збільшення):

> [image]

Те саме каже «Словник української мови» в 11 томах:

> [ПОВІ́**ШЕ**НИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/povishenyj), а, е. Дієпр. пас. мин. ч. до повісити. <…>
>
> ---
>
> [ПОВІ́**ША**НИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/povishanyj), а, е. Дієпр. пас. мин. ч. до повішати.  <…>

Приклади, наведені Аналолієм у його [відповіді](/a/5095), теж є всього-навсього помилками розпізнавання:

- [Станіслав Губерначук «Прадавність української мови»](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Hubernachuk_Stanisalav/Pradavnist_ukrainskoi_movy.pdf#page=256):

  > [image: А. Кримський відшукав у рукописах Русі-України такі приклади на цю рису: посажаний, (замість — посажений), повітаний, засмоляний, казняний.]
- [Києво-Печерський Патерик / [Пер. з церковно-слов’ян. М. Кашуба, Н. Пікулик]. – Львів: Монастир Монахів Студ. Уставу. Вид. від. “Свічадо”, 2001. – 191 с.: іл. – (Середньовіччя VI–XIV ст.). – (Джерела християнського Сходу)](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=SHcRAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22):

  > [image: «На дереві має бути повішаний», — відповідали йому.]

Comment: Жахлива описка! (Чи скоріше, недолік системи OCR, що погано розрізняє курсивні літери _"ш"_ і _"т"_, а також відсутність вичитки).
Так можна було і якісь нові мовні теорії почати вигадувати :)

Comment: @bobbib, хотів був посперечатися з Вами, бо мені здавалося, що це саме одрук у книзі — але знайшов неоцифровану версію книги, і знаєте, що — Ви праві.